# Why i am getting this error? TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, string

I am getting the following error in my code what did I do wrong:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 15, in <module>
    print_formatted(n)
  File "Solution.py", line 9, in print_formatted
    print(d.ljust([2,' ']),o.ljust([2,' ']),h.ljust([2,' ']),b.ljust([2,' ']))
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

    TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

The code looks like this:

```
def print_formatted(number):
    for i in range(1,number+1):

        d=str(i)
        o=str(oct(i))[2:]
        h=(str(hex(i))[2:]).capitalize()
        b=str(bin(i))[2:]
        print(d.ljust([2,' ']),o.ljust([2,' ']),h.ljust([2,' ']),b.ljust([2,' ']))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    print_formatted(n)
```

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Comment: Can you please explain your expectation?  Show us an example input and the output you’re after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ljust` takes two arguments, not a list of two elements. Use this:

```
print(d.ljust(2, ' '), o.ljust(2, ' '), h.ljust(2, ' '), b.ljust(2, ' '))
```